# How do I check a file's permissions in linux using Go

Tags: linux, go

I'm learning Go and the first project I want to do is to write a replacement for the Linux find shell program. I wrote a replacement for it in python in less than an hour. This is a much bigger challenge.

The problem I'm having is as Goes `filepath.Walk` traverses my file system it spits out a bunch of permission denied messages to the screen.
I need a way of checking the files permissions before `filepath.Walk` touches them.

Answer (score 10):

In `go` the file permission is defined in [`os.FileMode`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode) in which the underlying type is an `uint32`. From documentation:

> A FileMode represents a file's mode and permission bits...
> ...
> The defined file mode bits are the most significant bits of the FileMode. The nine least-significant bits are the standard Unix rwxrwxrwx permissions. The values of these bits should be considered part of the public API and may be used in wire protocols or disk representations: they must not be changed, although new bits might be added.

You can retrieve the `FileMode` through [`os.Stat`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Stat) or [`os.LStat`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Lstat) function which returns a [`FileInfo`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo), e.g.

```
info, err := os.Stat("file/directory name")
```

then the `FileMode` can be obtained by calling `info.Mode()`. To check the permission, performs *bitwise* operation to the mode bits, e.g.

```
//Check 'others' permission
m := info.Mode()
if m&(1<<2) != 0 {
    //other users have read permission
} else {
    //other users don't have read permission
}
```

If you're visiting directory/file(s) using `filepath.Walk` function, since the `WalkFunc` (the second argument of `Walk`) is defined as

```
type WalkFunc func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error
```

the `FileInfo` for certain *path* is available as the second argument of `WalkFunc`, thus you can check the permission directly using `info.Mode()` without calling `os.Stat` or `os.Lstat` inside the body of the closure or function passed to `filepath.Walk.`

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the bit shift works or at least the syntax?

Comment: @Hack_Hut  if read permission for others (`rwx`) is set, then this bit will be set to 1 ( permission ends with `1xx` for example octal value `0o037` ).  `1<<2` is `100` in binary. `&` will return 1 if the third bit of permission is 1 as well ( read permission to others). http://www.filepermissions.com/file-permissions-index lists all the permissions.

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve the permissions in string form e.i: *r, w, x*. Like this:

```
func printPermissions(filename string) {
    info, err := os.Stat(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mode := info.Mode()

    fmt.Print("Owner: ")
    for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {
        fmt.Print(string(mode.String()[i]))
    }

    fmt.Print("\nGroup: ")
    for i := 4; i < 7; i++ {
        fmt.Print(string(mode.String()[i]))
    }

    fmt.Print("\nOther: ")
    for i := 7; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Print(string(mode.String()[i]))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For **unix** permissions and modern go you can use literals.

```golang
filePath := "/tmp/testfile"
fileStats, err := os.Stat(filePath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("file does not exist: %v", err)
}

permissions := fileStats.Mode().Perm()
if permissions != 0o600 {
    log.Fatalf("incorrect permisisons %s (0%o), must be 0600 for '%s'", permissions, permissions, filePath)
}

// check for specific permissions: user read, user write
if permissions&0b110000000 == 0b110000000 {
    fmt.Printf("user has read and write permission\n")
}

// check for specific permission: user write
if permissions&0b010000000 == 0b010000000 {
    fmt.Printf("user has write permission\n")
}

// check for specific permission: user read
// breakup for better readability
if permissions&0b100_000_000 == 0b100_000_000 {
    fmt.Printf("user has read permission\n")
}
```

**A nice explaination on permissions as bits and octal**
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79100